# Code gives -1 and not 4. method should return one value

Tags: java

```
package com.ibm.prac;

public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {1,2,5,7,9,10};
    int no = 9;

    int index = returnIndex(arr,no, 0, arr.length-1, arr.length/2);
    System.out.println(index);
}

private static int returnIndex(int[] arr, int no, int start, int end, int mid) {
    int index = -1;
    if(no == arr[mid]){
        index = mid;
        return index;

    }
    else if(no > arr[mid]){
        if(index == -1){
        start = mid;
        mid = (start + end)/2;
        returnIndex(arr, no, start, end, mid);
        }
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("write");
    }

    return index;   
}

}
```

Why this piece of code is returning -1. It should return 4.
It takes value as 4 and then again goes to else statement and gives -1 as output

Comment: What does the code do? Input and expected outputs?

Comment: You are doing absolutly nothing wih you recursive method call. Actually returning the value `return returnIndex(arr, no, start, end, mid);` will fix one of the problems of your code. But even then it will only work  for values that are to the right side of the middle of yur array because you completly ignore the possibility that the value might be to the left (aka `no < arr[mid]`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is

```
else if(no > arr[mid]){
    if(index == -1){
    start = mid;
    mid = (start + end)/2;
    index = returnIndex(arr, no, start, end, mid);
    }
}
```

You've lost your index after returning from recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Use the debugger of eclipse or IntelliJ. However the conditions are not complete and the recursion is skipping some of the edge cases.